# Getting Graphics-Object or Bitmap from BrowserField on Blackberry

Tags: html, blackberry, browser, graphics, browserfield

I would like to get the Bitmap of the content of a webpage as it is displayed in the BrowserField. Therefore I'd need the Graphic-object of the browser field. But the paint-method is protected unfortunately.
Is there a way to get this?

Thank's

Comment: Your trying to access a bitmap image which is rendered within the HTML of a browser field ?

Comment: yep, i need the rendered result as an image

Answer (score 0):

Normally, if you want to do some custom drawing with a field ie. draw into the field's graphics context, you'd subclass Field and override the *paint* method. However, when it comes to BrowserField, you can't do that because it's declared *final*.

There is a workaround for this, though. You can subclass a Manager and add your BrowserField to an instance of that manager. So, for example, if you want to add your BrowserField instance to a VerticalFieldManager, you can use the following code to get access to the Graphics object the browser will be drawn into. In this sample code, you'll see that I use the graphics object and manager's superclass implementation to draw into a bitmap. Then, that bitmap is drawn to the screen.

```
VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager() {
    // Override to gain access to Field's drawing surface
    //
    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {

        // Create a bitmap to draw into 
        //
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(vfm.getVirtualWidth(), vfm.getVirtualHeight());

        // Create a graphics context to draw into the bitmap
        //
        Graphics g = Graphics.create(b);

        // Give this graphics context to the superclass implementation
        // so it will draw into the bitmap instead of the screen
        //
        super.paint(g);

        // Now, draw the bitmap
        //
        graphics.drawBitmap(0, 
                0, 
                vfm.getVirtualWidth(), 
                vfm.getVirtualHeight(), 
                b, 
                0, 
                0);

    }
};
```

And, there you have a Bitmap containing the contents of the manager. Should note, though, that this has the potential to consume a lot of memory.

Comment: Completely working MainScreen implementation with BrowserField and BitmapField. Scroll to bottom of screen and you will see an exact copy of the BrowserField displayed in the BitmapField. Enjoy! http://pastebin.com/9qRTgdgH

Comment: I'm sorry, but even with your code I only see an empty white space in the bitmapField and above the twitter content from the browser-field.

Comment: I'm using OS 5 9550 simulator. What are you using?

Comment: I guess it doesn't work on OS7. Tested it on simulators: 9810, (a newer version than before of) 9900 and on 9350. Seems as if another Graphics object is used for rendering the html-content.